# AWS Kubernetes: Deploying set of pods in the same namespace to Fargate and others to EC2 node group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have an AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster. I have a set of EC2 nodes and also have configured a Fargate profile to launch pods in Fargate compute. Say I am running an App in namespace `alex-ns`. Can I somehow deploy 1 set of pods in Fargate and 1 set of different pods in my other EC2 nodegroup if they all reside in `alex-ns`? It appears that if I set the Fargate profile to match with namespace `alex-ns` everything is Launched in Fargate. However, I would like to split it up specifically based on labels or something. The reason I'm asking is I have to run a Pod that requires more than 32 GB of RAM that's available in Fargate so my pod must run in my EC2 node group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I somehow deploy 1 set of pods in Fargate and 1 set of different pods in my other EC2 nodegroup if they all reside in alex-ns?

Yes, you can also add **labels** to the [Fargate Profile selector](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/180_fargate/creating-profile/) in addition to the namespace `alex-ns`.

The EKS documentation has more info about [Fargate Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-profile.html), an example selector for your case:

```
    "selectors": [
        {
            "namespace": "alex-ns",
            "labels": {
                "fargate": "yes"
            }
        }
```